# Spark: use underlying type of dataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm creating a dataframe in spark like this:

```
DF: DataFrame = df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(myTypeRDD, getMyTypeSchema())
```

`MyType` is a complex data type.

For testing purposes I want to use it as a `MyType` collection.

**My attempts:**

1. Trying to cast on the dataFrame:

`DF.as[MyType]` & `DF.map(row => row.asInstanceOf[MyType]` gave:

> No Encoder found for org.joda.time.DateTime

2. Trying to cast after collecting:

`DF.collect().asInstanceOf[MyType]` gave:

> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to MyType

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688945/convert-string-with-form-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-to-joda-datetime-in-dataframe-in-spa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string with form "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" to joda datetime in dataframe in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688945/convert-string-with-form-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm-to-joda-datetime-in-dataframe-in-spa)

Comment: How about `DF.rdd.collect` ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796176/unsupportedoperationexception-error-converting-string-to-datetime-using-joda-tim